# How to improve this C# Linq Concat Example?

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

The following C# Linq example displays the correct records in a serverSide datatable. However, when I add the following line: `data = data.Concat(unconfirmed);`, it increases the page/datatable load time from ~500 ms to ~2 seconds when `year` equals the current year. Searching by the current year displays the most amount of records, but they are only ~90. Searching by a previous year displays ~10 records at most and it only takes ~500 ms for the page/datatable to load:

```
var data = _db.ResidencyConfirmations.AsQueryable();

var year = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[11][search][value]")[0];
var showConfirmed = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[12][search][value]")[0];

int.TryParse(year, out var resultYear);

data = data.Where(rc => rc.Application.ApplicationType.Label == "Home Rehab");

var allNotesReleased = data.Where(rc => rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .Where(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == 6)
        .Select(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.ActivityPhase)
        .FirstOrDefault() == "All Notes Released" &&
    rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .Where(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == 6)
        .Select(aap => aap.ActivityPhaseDate)
        .FirstOrDefault().Year >= resultYear);

var complete = data.Where(rc => rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .Where(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .Max(x => x.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep))
        .Select(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.ActivityPhase)
        .FirstOrDefault() == "Complete" &&
    rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .Where(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == 5)
        .Select(aap => aap.ActivityPhaseDate)
        .FirstOrDefault().Year < resultYear);

var unconfirmed = complete.Where(rc => !rc.Application.ResidencyConfirmations
    .Any(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate.Year == resultYear))
    .GroupBy(rc => rc.Application.AppNumber)
    .Select(rc => rc.OrderByDescending(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate)
    .FirstOrDefault());

data = allNotesReleased.Concat(complete)
    .Where(rc => rc.ResidencyConfirmationDate.Year == resultYear);

if (showConfirmed == "false")
    data = data.Where(rc => !rc.Deed || !rc.Utility || !rc.VitalRecords);

data = data.Concat(unconfirmed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it compiles, written in text editor, but query should be faster. Note that instead of using `.Year` introduced range variables, it will speedup query if you have indexes on date.

```cs
var year = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[11][search][value]")[0];
var showConfirmed = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[12][search][value]")[0];

int.TryParse(year, out var resultYear);

var startOfTheYear = new DateTime(resultYear, 1, 1);
var nextYear = startOfTheYear.AddYears(1);

var data = _db.ResidencyConfirmations.AsQueryable();

data = data.Where(rc => rc.Application.ApplicationType.Label == "Home Rehab");


var allNotesReleased = 
    from rc in data
    from aap in rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .Where(aap => aap.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == 6)
        .Take(1)
    where 
        aap.ActivityPhas.ActivityPhase == "All Notes Released" &&
        app.ActivityPhaseDate >= startOfTheYear &&
        rc.ResidencyConfirmationDate >= startOfTheYear && rc.ResidencyConfirmationDate < nextYear
    select rc;

var complete = 
    from rc in data
    from aap in rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .OrderByDescending(aap => aap.WorkFlowStep)
        .Take(1)
    from aap2 in rc.Application.ApplicationActivityPhas
        .Where(aap2 => aap2.ActivityPhas.WorkFlowStep == 5)
        .Take(1)
    where 
        aap.ActivityPhas.ActivityPhase == "Complete" &&
        app2.ActivityPhaseDate < startOfTheYear &&
        rc.ResidencyConfirmationDate >= startOfTheYear && rc.ResidencyConfirmationDate < nextYear
    select rc;

var unconfirmed = complete
    .Where(rc => !rc.Application.ResidencyConfirmations
        .Any(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate >= startOfTheYear && x.ResidencyConfirmationDate < nextYear)
    )
    .GroupBy(rc => rc.Application.AppNumber)
    .Select(rc => rc
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate)
        .First()
    );

if (showConfirmed == "false")
    data = data.Where(rc => !rc.Deed || !rc.Utility || !rc.VitalRecords);

data = data.Concat(unconfirmed);
```

Comment: In the allNotesReleased where clause, I changed app to aap. In the second from of complete, I added ActivityPhas. before WorkFlowStep. In the complete where clause, I changed app2 to aap2. In the unconfirmed select statement, I changed First() to FirstOrDefault(), First() produces an error. With these changes, the correct records are not displayed. Searching by any year displays the same 36 records with some differences in column data. Searching by year 2016 displays a record with an Activity Phase of Complete year of 2022 for example. The year should be > than Activity Phase Complete year.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance and to display the correct records, I made the following changes/additions:

```
if (resultYear == DateTime.Now.Year)
    data = data.Where(rc => rc.Application.ApplicationType.Label == "Home Rehab")
        .GroupBy(rc => rc.Application.AppNumber)
        .Select(rc => rc.OrderByDescending(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate)
        .FirstOrDefault());
else
    data = data.Where(rc => rc.Application.ApplicationType.Label == "Home Rehab");
    
IQueryable<ResidencyConfirmation> unconfirmed = null;

if (resultYear == DateTime.Now.Year)
    unconfirmed = complete.Where(rc => !rc.Application.ResidencyConfirmations
        .Any(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate.Year == resultYear));
else
    unconfirmed = complete.Where(rc => !rc.Application.ResidencyConfirmations
        .Any(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate.Year == resultYear))
        .GroupBy(rc => rc.Application.AppNumber)
        .Select(rc => rc.OrderByDescending(x => x.ResidencyConfirmationDate)
        .FirstOrDefault());
```

It now takes right under 1 second for the page/datatable to load.

Comment: To avoid duplication and simplify the code further, I'd suggest moving the repeated parts out of the if loops. I.e.: (1) Moving `data = data.Where()` out of the if loop, and inside the `if`, doing `data = data.GroupBy()...`. (2) Moving `unconfirmed = complete.Where(...Any())` out of the if loop, invert the if condition, and inside the (new) `if`, doing `unconfirmed = unconfirmed.GroupBy()...`. Then there will be no need for any `else` statements.

Comment: Thank you. I applied your suggestion.